# How to get a certain part from file path that being saved as a String - Android / Java

Tags: java, android, string

I"m saving a file path as a String -

```
 String selectedPath1 = getPath(selectedImageUri);

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Now i'm the selectedPath1 String is shown like that -

```
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/201403_231.jpg
```

Now what iwould like to do is to save the - 201403_231.jpg - as a separate String.

So how can i "cut" it from the String?

Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: Use Split or subString function of String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `substring()` and `lastIndexOf()` methods. Note that you need to add 1 to the last index to not take the `/` character.

```
String selectedPath1 = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/201403_231.jpg";
String lastPart = selectedPath1.substring(selectedPath1.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Output is `201403_231.jpg`.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel when there is the File class to do it for you?

Comment: Those 2 methods of String are hardly much effort. Didn't really think about File class for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

Does android not have the `File` type that java has?

```
String filename = new File(uri).getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
selectedPath1.substring(selectedPath1.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
```

This would return the file name.

Comment: Forgive me for any formatting issues. I'm using a mobile client

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression: `[^/]*$`. Example:

```
String mydata = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/201403_231.jpg";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^//]*$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
if (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Output:

```
201403_231.jpg
```

Comment: "Sometimes when people have a problem they think 'I think I'll use regular expressions'..."